# Android emulator - Could not reset the state on your device

Tags: android-emulator

I've just updated Android Studio to the 4.1 version but I'm experiencing some troubles after the update. Android Studio is giving me an error message "Could not reset the state on your device",
screenshot below. I've tried to delete and recreate the emulator but the problem persists. No success with adb.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go into the Android Studio SDK manager and redownload the Android OS you are running on your emulator. Perhaps a little corruption happened in the update?